# The requested page could not be found - Drupal 7

Tags: php, ubuntu, drupal

I have installed  the **[Drupal 7](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Drupal)**  on my Ubuntu 14.10.

But i have always getting this error. Have a look [image]

Any idea ?!

Comment: It seems to be an error in the path. Make a double check

Comment: isn't an error in the path @aminejallouli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ***I found the solution.***

It's just about **the permission** !!

Execute  this command on terminal :

> sudo chmod a+w drupal

and we have this ( have a look ) => [image: ²]